# How are values for bundle product stored in the database?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, bundled-product

I wanted to know the flow which is being use while saving bundle product.
In database their are two main tables, `catalog_product_bundle_option` and `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`, which store data related to options of bundle item of product.

But how does Magento know when to store data in `catalog_product_bundle_option` and when in `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`?

It is not like static type of attribute which is used for saving EAV data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain brief about Bundle product. the below 3 tables important for bundle product

> catalog_product_bundle_option
>
> catalog_product_bundle_option_value
>
> catalog_product_bundle_selection

**Example** :

**Sprite Yoga Companion Kit** consider as bundle product.

**Sprite Stasis Ball :** : consider as bundle associate bundle item title.

1) Sprite Stasis Ball 55 cm - This product as simple product want to display as radio button

2) Sprite Stasis Ball 65 cm - This product as simple product want to display as radio button

3) Sprite Stasis Ball 75 cm - This product as simple product want to display as radio button

[image]

**How it will store in Table?**

**catalog_product_bundle_selection :**  associate bundle items and price are stored in this table.

**catalog_product_bundle_option** : How we want to display (Radio,Multiple select, dropdown,checkbox) is stored in this table. In this table "Type" is the colum as (Radio,Multiple select, dropdown,checkbox).

**catalog_product_bundle_option_value** : option type title stored in table. **Title** is the value of option. (Example : Sprite Stasis Ball)

Hope it will clear i think

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if catalog_product_bundle_option_value is used to store option selection then what is the use of catalog_product_bundle_selection

Comment: I have brief explain here. hope it will helpful for you

Comment: Shall i know is it clear? or need any input on this

Answer (score 1):

Both tables are always used. The Options have titles which can be localized per store view.

`catalog_product_bundle_option` identifies the option and contains global values, `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` contains the store specific values (i.e. the title).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if catalog_product_bundle_option_value is used to store option selection then what is the use of catalog_product_bundle_selection

Comment: @AnishMadankar Ah, my mistake. `value` is actually the localized title for the option (can be different per store view). I'll update the answer